# How to enable the "draggable mode" on a customized item?

Tags: ios, xcode, draggable, xib

So here is my problem:

I've created a `PostIt.xib` (which is just composed with 2 labels and 2 textFields).

On my storyboard I've added a button and when I press it, it call his function `addNewPostIt` which... Add a new PostIt! :D

So, what I want to do now is to `DragNDrop` this PostIt... I really don't know how to process, so if someone could help me it would be very nice!
Thanks a lot!

Here is my function: (x and y are static Integer which are auto incremented).

```
- (IBAction)addNewPostIt:(id)sender {

   PostIt *postit2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostIt" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];

   postit2.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 400, 100);

   [self.view addSubview:postit2];

   x+=100;
   y+=100;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer), specifically a [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/).